# How can I round a number to the nearest hundredth using vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, math

For example, if I entered the number 2.5 into an input field and wanted to turn it into 0.025, would I use Math.round() or some other way?

My goal is to take the decimal number entered into the input field and store the hundredth of that number into a variable in JS.

Here's what I've got so far:

```js
function calculator() {
    const hundredthNumber = document.getElementById('numberInput').getElementByTagName('input').value;

}
```

```html
<div class="inputSection" id="numberInput">
  <h3>What is your number?</h3>
  <input type="number" placeholder="">
</div>
```

Comment: I'd start by dividing the number by 100 instead of rounding. If you want to limit the number to three decimal places, see [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Answer (score -1):

You can Use this Code :

```
function roundoff(x) 
{
 return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2)/100;
 }
console.log(roundoff(2.5));
```